# Ansys CFD: Ways in which to calculate the lift and drag coefficient accross the distribution of the surface

Tags: ansys

How do you calculate the lift and drag coefficients across the surface in Ansys CFD Post? How do you import Cd,Cl,Cm coefficient values from FLuent to Ansys CFD post. This is for my CFD project, with me simulating transonic flow over a circular and square cylinder.

So that I can generate Cd and Cl over the x[m] distribution of the surface.

I saved and imported my case (.cas) and data files(.dat) and loaded them up in Ansys Fluent, but these new variables doesn't show up ( the Cd, Cl, Cm and the heat transfer values).